# Visual Studio c++ LoadLibary error: The program can't start because dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to connect my program to a dll.

Connect code:

```
HINSTANCE lib;

    lib = LoadLibrary("DLL.dll");
    if (lib)
    {
        cout << "Libary Loaded !";
        FreeLibrary(lib);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<GetLastError();
    }
```

DLL code(at DLL.cpp):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "DLL.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int f()
{
    return 11;
}
```

Once I run the program I get this error:

*The program can't start because <dllname> is missing from your computer.*

After each dll request I downloaded the dll from the internet and put it into 
the folder where the dll and the program are. Here are some of the dll I requested:

1. VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll
2. api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-2.dll

Once I get that error after clicking 'OK' button I get `GetLastError() = 126`.

I tried to link my program to the lib `VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll` just to check if it is going to load the library and it did. So the problem is probably in the library I try to connect to.

I work with Visual Studio 2015.Both the DLL and the program are compiled in x86(32bit). I have all redistribution packages installed. I tried with x64(64bit) but got same errors and the same dlls requests. I tried to put DLL in build and in debug folders both didn't work.

I also tried using `**LoadLibaryA**` and `**LoadLibaryW**` but these didn't work as well.

PS: Just tried dll I created in CodeBlocks instead of Visual Studio 2015 and it connected. Should be a Visual Studio Compiler specific problem.

Comment: "..can't start because is missing..." are you sure? There is a word missing in that error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look to the syntax of **LoadLibrary** function:

```
HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibrary(
   _In_ LPCTSTR lpFileName
);
```

You see that there is no option to specify from where to load your library

Instead use the function **LoadLibraryEx** witch has the following syntax:

```
HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibraryEx(
   _In_       LPCTSTR lpFileName,
   _Reserved_ HANDLE  hFile,
   _In_       DWORD   dwFlags
);
```

So with the use of [dwFlags parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx), you can now specify from where your program can try to load your library.

example of dwFlags:

> LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR   0x00000200:

witch means:

```
 If this value is used, the application's installation directory is searched  
 for the DLL and its dependencies. Directories in the standard search path  
 are not searched.
```

So to resume, you have to use the **dwFlags parameter** you want in order to find your dll.

Comment: Good. So you have a lot of flexibility with that function.

Comment: Not enough tho I can't use dll included functions in the DLL.dll.Like std::cin  etc.

Comment: I've to verify. Update your code if any (main code from witch you load the dll)