# Visual C++ Creating DLL missing dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I just created a C++ DLL using Visual Studio 2015. 
I did no edits to the default source.
Then I used DependencyWalker to see all my DLL dependencies and I saw this:

[image: this]

You can clearly see that most of the dll required are missing.

When I try to connect to such a dll I get error for those libaries missing...

I tried connecting to a DLL made in CodeBlocks and it didn't give me any errors.

Whats going on ?

PS:

Here is the error message:

> The program can't start because MSVCP140_APP.dll is missing from your
>   computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

More information of my problem can [be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561423/visual-studio-c-loadlibary-error-the-program-cant-start-because-dll-is-missi):

Comment: What's going on is that you didn't build the DLL correctly in Visual Studio.  What steps you are missing?  I suggest you get a full tutorial on how to create DLL's in Visual Studio.  You have to know each and every step of what you're doing, and not merely "pushing buttons" in the IDE.

Comment: well I used Build Solution.I do not click random buttons.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit DLL or 64-bit DLL?  What functions will be exported?  Do you use a .DEF file?  What runtime are you linking to (multithreaded, multithreaded DLL, etc.)?  How are you testing the DLL?  `LoadLibrary`?  Implicit linking?  Also, load the "CodeBlocks" DLL in Dependency Walker.  What differences do you see in the output?  And not "random button" is what I'm referring to -- what I am speaking of is not knowing what the options you're using actually do.  If you did know, then you would be able to identify what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It is 32 bit (tried with 64bit same thing).As I said in the question I didn't add any functions to the moment . For code blocks dll I see libaries my Dependency Walker finds.Will screenshot them to you if you think will help you reslove my problem. I tried to makethe problem the simplest I I can so I wouldn't need to explain every single step.Just hit button for project create dll.Build it. Create Win32 project connect to the dll using LoadLibary and you will probably see errors yourself.Or just try opening the dll using Dependency Walker

Comment: Sorry, but I build DLL's every working day using Visual Studio 2015, and I do not come across this problem.  One reason is that I know exactly what each step in the DLL build process consists of.  First, stick to 32-bit DLL's, just randomly trying things won't solve the problem.  The DLL should be a very simple one with a single exported function.  Build it and test.

Comment: I can't imagine simpler than the one I use atm. I tried with one exported function only.I got the same thing.The only way I can get the dll to work is though LoadLibaryEx.However I use it with flag do not reslove references so all libaries in the dll are nullable .Even cin and cout can't be used that case

Comment: here is where I asked yesterday:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561423/visual-studio-c-loadlibary-error-the-program-cant-start-because-dll-is-missi

Comment: Please edit your question providing exact error messages in text form (no pictures). Add [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible

Comment: you can find the information on this post. It did fix my dll not working problem but I can't use dependency libaries at all.

Comment: How do you create your DLL project? (The exact name of the template you are using). How do you create your application project?

Comment: Visual C++ -> DLL (Universal Windows)

Comment: And application (executable)?

Comment: Visual C++ -> Win32 Project

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question consists of two parts.

### Part one

> You can clearly see that most of the dll required are missing.

`api-ms-win-*` family of modules, introduced with Windows 7, consists of tiny stub DLLs that redirect function calls inside core libraries (such as `kernel32`, `user32` etc.) to their implementations elsewhere.

They are not really missing, it's just Dependency Walker is ridiculously out of date (latest version dates back to year 2006) and doesn't know where to search. In fact, you can inspect any successfully running windows binary that links to system libraries and see the very same picture.

`api-ms-win-*` it's an internal details of Windows implementation and you shouldn't worry about it, unless you are working at Microsoft in Windows kernel team.

### Part two

> When I try to connect to such a dll I get error for those libaries
>   missing... I tried connecting to a DLL made in CodeBlocks and it
>   didn't give me any errors.

```
Visual C++ -> DLL (Universal Windows)
Visual C++ -> Win32 Project
```

You are mixing Win32 application (uses good 'ol Win32 API) and [Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx) libary (that what was Windows RT before).

Instead you should either:

- (the Win32 way) create a usual Win32 DLL, by using `Visual C++ -> Win32 Project` template and then choosing `Application type: DLL` and then link it with your Win32 App.
- (the WinRT way) create a *Universal Windows App* to link against *Universal Windows DLL*

Code blocks works here because it does not (and will probably never) support UWP.

P.S. You should never explicitly link against `VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll` or worse `api-ms-win-*.dll` unless you know what you are dong.

P.P.S. To be completely honest, you [can mix UWP and Win32 in a limited way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx). But let's call it an advanced topic and leave it as an exercise to a curious reader.

Links:

- [Windows 7 Kernel Architecture Changes - api-ms-win-core files](http://www.nirsoft.net/articles/windows_7_kernel_architecture_changes.html)
- [Windows 7 – Kernel API Refactoring](https://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/windows-7-kernel-api-refactoring/)